# A conjecture on circular permutations of n elements in an abelian group of odd order

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, permutations, abelian-groups

In 2013 I formulated the following conjecture in additive combinatorics.

**Conjecture.** Let $G$ be an additive abelian group of odd order, and let $A$ be a subset of $G$ with $|A|=n>2$. Then, there is a circular permutation $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of all the elements of $A$ such that all the adjacent sums $ a_1+a_2,\ldots,a_{n-1}+a_n,a_n+a_1$
are pairwise distinct.

Recently, Mr. Yu-Xuan Ji, a student at Nanjing Univ., verified this conjecture for $|G|<30$.

I'm even unable to show the conjecture for $G=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ with $p$ an odd prime.

Any ideas towards the solution of this conjecture? Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Perhaps what was meant is "there is an enumeration" rather than "there is a circular permutation"?

Comment: I use the word "circular" since we consider $a_n$ and $a_1$  adjacent.

Comment: Given a choice of ordering of the elements of a set $A$ as $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, the standard understanding of "circular permutation" of that ordering is one of the form $a_i,\ldots,a_n,a_1\ldots,a_{i-1}$. If one understands the conjecture in this way, it does not make sense.

Comment: The conjecture was contained in my paper available from http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/196a.pdf

Comment: Perhaps a better word is a cyclic permutation (in cycle notation) "$(a_1\cdots a_n)$".

Comment: For cyclic groups, replacing addition with subtraction in the question gives a relation to graceful labellings of graphs. For cyclic groups, these exist when $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$ but not when $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$ by a theorem of Rosa. Unfortunately this doesn't help answer the question...